scrollbar disappears when clicking dropdown menu
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { buttonVariants } from "../ui/button";

import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu";

export default function SignInButton() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (session && session.user) {
    return (
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownMenuTrigger className="right-0 outline py-2 px-2 rounded-md">User</DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <DropdownMenuContent>
          <DropdownMenuLabel>My Account</DropdownMenuLabel>
          <DropdownMenuSeparator />
          <DropdownMenuItem>Subscription</DropdownMenuItem>
          <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => signOut()}>LogOut</DropdownMenuItem>
        </DropdownMenuContent>
      </DropdownMenu>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button className={buttonVariants({ variant: "outline" })} onClick={() => signIn()}>
      LogIn
    </button>
  );
}

I used shadcn Dropdown menu, and when I click it, the menu button move right and chrome scroll bar disappear. what should i do? can i solve it with tailwind css?

It's only a guess, but I guess the shadcn dropdown menu creates an invisible full screen overlay and disables scrolling.

This drove me crazy! I had this same issue . You can fix it by adding just one line of CSS to your global styles:

/* globals.css */

#__next {
    @apply h-full;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


This makes sure the scrollbar space is always there, so your content doesn't jump around.

This is not the ideal solution as to solve it we impose scrollbar to be always there.

Your issue is resolved by applying:

<DropdownMenu modal={false}>

As per the docs, the modal is set to be true by default which blocks any interactions by the user with any other elements on the page. You set it to false and they can now scroll up and down the page with the menu open.
P.S. The fix the other user provided in the global.css actually causes a hydration error and should not be used.

This is the correct solution. Thanks!
